# getting ('Connection aborted.', OSError(0, 'Error')) in Azure ML

Tags: python, bert-language-model, azure-machine-learning-service

I am unable to load BERT model in Azure ML notebook.

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
model = SentenceTransformer('all-mpnet-base-v2')
```

I am getting this error:

```
File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py:645, in Session.send(self, request, **kwargs)
    642 start = preferred_clock()
    644 # Send the request
--> 645 r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    647 # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)
    648 elapsed = preferred_clock() - start

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py:501, in HTTPAdapter.send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    498             raise
    500 except (ProtocolError, socket.error) as err:
--> 501     raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
    503 except MaxRetryError as e:
    504     if isinstance(e.reason, ConnectTimeoutError):
    505         # TODO: Remove this in 3.0.0: see #2811

ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError(0, 'Error'))
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this package upgrading and that supports the version of python. There is a chance of upgrading the TLS and SSL version in the app functioning portal.

[image]

Check the TLS version and all the certificates.

This is also because of older version. Try to execute the below code block so solve the error.

```
pip install -U sentence-transformers
```